# Evenly select Records on categorical column with Repeating Sequence and pagination in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query

Database: Postgres
I have a `product(id, title, source, ...)` table which contains almost 500K records.
An example of data is:

```
| Id | title    | source   |
|:---|---------:|:--------:|
| 1  | product1 | source1  |
| 2  | product2 | source1  |
| 3  | product3 | source1  |
| 4  | product4 | source1  |
| .  | ........ | source1  |
| .  | ........ | source2  |
| x  | productx | source2  |
|x+n |productX+n| sourceN  |
```

There are are 5 distinct source values. And all records have source values random.

I need to get paginated results in such a way that:
If I need to select 20 products then the results set should contain results equally distributed based on source and should be in a repeating sequence. 2 products from each source till the last source and again next 2 products from each source.
For example:

```
| #  | title    | source   |
|:---|---------:|:--------:|
| 1  | product1 | source1  |
| 2  | product2 | source1  |
| 3  | product3 | source2  |
| 4  | product4 | source2  |
| 5  | product5 | source3  |
| 6  | product6 | source3  |
| 7  | product7 | source4  |
| 8  | product8 | source4  |
| 9  | product9 | source5  |
| 10 |product10 | source5  |
| 11 | ........ | source1  |
| 12 | ........ | source1  |
| 13 | ........ | source2  |
| 14 | ........ | source2  |
| .. | ........ | .......  |
| 20 | ........ | source5  |
```

What is the optimized PgSql query to achieve the above scenario considering the LIMIT, OFFSET, sources can increase or decrease?